# VueFire with vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vuefire

Hi i'm using vuefire with vite when i try to

```
import { VueFire, VueFireAuth } from 'vuefire'
```

I get this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name (at chunk-TZOYARRL.js?v=786f7321:13756:9)
```

Comment: You know that you don't need any `VueFire` to use Firebase? And if you learn to use Firebase, you can use it later in any framework you want? Same as, you don't need any state management system like Pinia or Vuex. Firebase Client SDK already have one. You need just enable it.

Comment: Is that relevant advice, Mises?  The point of any framework or library is to reduce tediousness so let's assume questioners asking about a specific lib want to use that lib for a reason.  Anyways, the question does not provide enough information.  soma, please provide enough code and details to produce a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Without that all we can do is guess and/or tell you to check the [docs](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html) to make sure you followed the install and usage instructions correctly.

Comment: I am using vuefire with cite with no issues at all. Make sure you have setup your firebase config and you have followed the docs to add vue.use vuefire and auth

Comment: I just downgrade the version and it worked